# Unity integration for updated Thunderbird profile

Tags: 11.10, thunderbird

I updated to 11.10, reusing my home partition so also my Thunderbird profile folder and now I see that the Messaging Menu and Unity integration extension 0.8 is not installed.

I'd like to keep my profile and do not start a new one, how do I install this missing extension? It appears as installed on new profiles, so it is on the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem - I found the extension in `/usr/lib/thunderbird-7.0/extensions` upon installing it message menu integration and Unity launcher badge work, but not the NotifyOSD upon receiving an email. Does anyone know how to remedy that?

Comment: Glad you found a problem, a separate question for notify-osd would be best, that way we have them nice and organized for the next person who needs help.